# JSONArray for array of String giving A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

I am reading a JSON string and trying to get value for a given key.
code to get value from JSON

```
private static void getKey(JSONObject jsonObject, String key) {
        boolean exist = jsonObject.has(key);
        Iterator<?> keys;
        String nextKey;

        if(!exist) {
            keys = jsonObject.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                nextKey = (String) keys.next();
                System.out.println("Key is :: " + nextKey);
                try {
                    if(jsonObject.get(nextKey) instanceof  JSONObject) {
                        if(!exist) {
                            getKey(jsonObject.getJSONObject(nextKey), key);
                        }
                    } else if(jsonObject.get(nextKey) instanceof JSONArray) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(nextKey);
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            String arrayValue = jsonArray.get(i).toString();
                            JSONObject innerJSONObject = new JSONObject(arrayValue.trim());
                            if(!exist) {
                                getKey(innerJSONObject, key);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else {
            parseJSONObject(jsonObject, key);
        }
    }
```

I am trying to parse this JSON String

```
String data = "[{\n" +
                "\t\"siteName\": \"tvt-ieee\",\n" +
                "\t\"personId\": \"43038888\",\n" +
                "\t\"editorId\": \"43038888-tvt-ieee\",\n" +
                "\t\"emails\": [{\n" +
                "\t\t\"emailAddress\": \"02superjh@gmail.com\"\n" +
                "\t}],\n" +
                "\t\"keywords\": [\"H.1.2 User/Machine Systems\",\"I.2 Artificial Intelligence\"],\n" +
                "}]";
        JSONArray jsonObject = new JSONArray(data);

        getKey(jsonObject.getJSONObject(0), "keywords");
```

but when I am trying to get value for key **"keywords"** it is throwing an error like
**A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]**

please help me how can I solve this issue?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Because the value of field `keywords` is an array of **string** not **JSON object**.

Comment: Why not use Objectparser? Why use manually?